# ¿Como leer archivos con extensiones xls y xlsx en la misma aplicación usando Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en [java](/questions/tagged/java) que me permita leer archivos `.xls` y `.xlsx`. Logré implementar la lectura de la extensión `.xls` con la librería Apache POI 3.13 mediante `HSSFWorkbook` y sé que necesito `XSSFWorkbook` para leer `.xlsx`.

Mi pregunta es si puedo hacer que la aplicación lea ambas extensiones y cómo.

Anexo parte del código con el cuál leo un archivo en .xls

```
HSSFWorkbook      workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (fileSystem);
    HSSFSheet         sheet    = workBook.getSheetAt (0); 
    int totalRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    System.out.println("Filas totales: "+totalRows);

    if (totalRows <= 4){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "El archivo debe contener al menos 1 artículo.", //Mensaje
                    "Mensaje de Advertencia", //Título
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }

    Iterator<?> rows     = sheet.rowIterator ();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    while (rows.hasNext ()) 
    {
        HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next(); 

        int rowNumber = row.getRowNum ();
        // muestra el número de fila
        System.out.println ("No. Fila: " + rowNumber);

        // get a row, iterate through cells.
        Iterator<?> cells = row.cellIterator (); 

        ArrayList<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (cells.hasNext ())
        {
            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next ();

            switch (cell.getCellType ())
            {
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC :
            {
                // NUMERIC CELL TYPE
                System.out.println ("Numerico: " + cell.getNumericCellValue ());
                rowData.add(cell.getNumericCellValue () + "");
                break;
            }
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK :
            {
                // NUMERIC CELL TYPE
                System.out.println ("Campo en Blanco" + cell.getErrorCellValue ());
                rowData.add(cell.getErrorCellValue () + "");
                break;


            }
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING :

            {
                // STRING CELL TYPE
                HSSFRichTextString richTextString = cell.getRichStringCellValue ();

                System.out.println ("String: " + richTextString.getString ());
                rowData.add(richTextString.getString ());
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                // types other than String and Numeric.
                System.out.println ("Tipo de dato no soportado.");
                break;
            }
            } // end switch

        } // end while
        data.add(rowData);
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Me parece que la pregunta es demasiado amplia como está planteada. Si la editas y muestras el pedazo de código con el que estás teniendo dificultades, seguramente tendrás más suerte obteniendo ayuda.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta,el código que edité es una parte de lo que utilizo para leer el archivo .xls , mi duda es si en esta misma aplicación puedo añadir XSSFWorkbook  para que la aplicación lea .xlsx o no es posible usar ambas lo que pretendo es seleccionar un archivo .xls o .xlsx y que la aplicación me permita leerlo

Comment: Genial la solución me sirvio fullll!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puedes leer ambos tipos de archivos usando POI. Acá te dejo un ejemplo básico para abrir archivos excel (xls o xlsx) usando las interfaces genéricas que provee POI:

```
File archivoExcel = new File("..."); //ruta del archivo xls o xlsx
Workbook libroExcel = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(archivoExcel)); //crear un libro excel
Sheet hojaActual = libroExcel.getSheetAt(0); //acceder a la primera hoja
Row filaActual = hojaActual.getRow(0); //acceder a la primera fila en la hoja
Cell celdaActual = filaActual.getCell(0); //acceder a la primera celda en la fila
```

Usando las interfaces `Workbook`, `Sheet`, `Row` y `Cell` no importa la fuente. Además, estas interfaces tienen métodos similares a los que encuentras para trabajar con HSSF, de manera que te familiarizas más rápido.

Comment: ¿Para qué usar PushbackInputStream? Lo quité y sigue funcionando.

Comment: @ArturoTena solo he copiado código que ya utilizaba antes. Sucede que ahora la implementación de POI envuelve el `InputStream` con un `PushbackInputStream` por ti.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y por el código estuve tratando de implementarlo pero no he logrado  hacerlo por ejemplo para recorrer los datos en HSSFWorkbook hay un metodo llamado rowIterator y no encuentro ningún método parecido en la clase Workbook que pones en el ejemplo podrías apoyarme con un ejemplo más completo para poder leer el archivo por favor?

Comment: @Manuel no recorres datos en HSSFWorkbook, lo que tu haces es acceder a una hoja (`Sheet`) de ese libro (`Workbook`), luego a una fila (`Row`) de esa hoja, y puedes ejecutar un `for` para obtener cada celda (`Cell`) de esa fila. Si conoces la fila, puedes hacer esto: `Row fila = ...; for (Cell celda : fila) { /* jugar con la celda */ }`

Comment: me sirvió bastante tu información muchas gracias por tu aporte, una pregunta más como podría recorrer todo el libro y hacer validaciones por columna (ej. columna 1 solo datos numéricos, columna 2 máximo 20 caracteres, etc) tienes alguna idea?

Comment: @Manuel poi no permite navegar por columna, solo por filas. Una vez que accedes a una fila, puedes acceder a la celda por columnas de acuerdo a su posición numérica. Basado en esto, solo puedes decir que para cada fila, la primera celda debe ser numérica, la segunda debe tener máximo 20 caracteres, etc. Este es un trabajo más tedioso y al menos esta librería te ofrece lo básico para realizarlo.

Comment: Si de echo se me hace muy tedioso ya que necesito validarlas por columna espero pueda encontrar alguna solución, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Hola quizá ya respondieron tu pregunta pero yo lo haría en un solo método de la siguiente manera: este método lee y escribe en jtable.

```
Workbook wb;
public String Importar(File archivo, JTable tablaD){
        String respuesta="No se pudo realizar la importación.";
        DefaultTableModel modeloT = new DefaultTableModel();
        tablaD.setModel(modeloT);
        tablaD.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        try {
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(archivo));//CREAMOS UNA REPRESENTACIÓN DE HOJA EXCEL
            Sheet hoja = wb.getSheetAt(0);//SELECCIONAMOS LA HOJA DE LA POSICIÓN -> 0 DEL LIBRO
            Iterator filaIterator = hoja.rowIterator();
            int indiceFila=-1;
            while (filaIterator.hasNext()) {                
                indiceFila++;
                Row fila = (Row) filaIterator.next();
                Iterator columnaIterator = fila.cellIterator();
                Object[] listaColumna = new Object[1000];
                int indiceColumna=-1;
                while (columnaIterator.hasNext()) {                    
                    indiceColumna++;
                    Cell celda = (Cell) columnaIterator.next();
                    if(indiceFila==0){
                        modeloT.addColumn(celda.getStringCellValue());
                    }else{
                        if(celda!=null){
                            switch(celda.getCellType()){
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]= (int)Math.round(celda.getNumericCellValue());
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]= celda.getStringCellValue();
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]= celda.getBooleanCellValue();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]=celda.getDateCellValue();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }                        
                    }
                }
                if(indiceFila!=0)modeloT.addRow(listaColumna);
            }
            respuesta="Importación exitosa";
        } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException | EncryptedDocumentException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```